# I've moved a site to GCE w/ LAMP and my PHP is outputting extra characters

Tags: php

My code looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>PHP Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

and outputs this:

Hello World

'; ?>

What are those extra characters doing there?

Thanks!

Comment: If you look at the page source, does it have your `<?php ...` right in there as plain text?

Comment: Also, is it a ".php" file or a ".html" file for example. It might not be being parsed as PHP - e.g. https://imgur.com/a/NwpI9

Comment: RT - I'm pretty sure it's plain text.  Ran fine at 1and1.

Comment: DC - HTML.  It's just a short test I wrote to understand a behavior in a larger script.

Comment: Also, FWIW, phpinfo() outputs nothing, but the LAMP stack is there and /etc/PHP5/ exists.

Comment: @DarenChandisingh Sounds like you've got enough info to write an answer. :)

Comment: RT - Sorry, I'm a bit of a noob.  can you clarify?

Comment: @TomMitchell Your web server must be configured to handle certain file extensions with PHP. If PHP isn't designated as the handler for .html files, the web server won't invoke the PHP interpreter to process those files, and they will be sent to the browswer as-is.

Comment: I see.  So it's ignoring "<?php echo '" and printing everything afterwards, rendering as pure HTML.  Makes sense.

Comment: @TJude I'm sorry, I didn't mean to be rude. Daren knew what your problem was, and your comment confirmed it. But your response hadn't "pinged" him, so that's what my comment was intended to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can't end a file in `.html` and expect your web server to parse it as PHP.

In that case it's sent directly to the browser without anything being parsed or executed as PHP.

Instead, save it as `index.php` for example, then view it in your browser. If you have PHP installed then you should get the output you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have saved your file with .html extension instead of .php.